# Bootstrap 5x Collapse on Mobile Only

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am trying to use the default collapse function in Bootstrap 5x when on Mobile devices only. Even though i have set the CSS media query (as researched), the .collapse is being ignored?

The collapsed DIV item should be visibly collapsed on Mobile and fully displayed on any device width larger than 768px? But it remains collapsed on all devices.

```
<style>

@media screen and (min-width: 768px){
  .collapse {
      display: block;
      height: auto !important;
      visibility: visible;
    }
    .collapsing{
      position: relative;
      height: unset !important;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
}

</style> 




<p>
  <a class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    EXAMPLE
  </a>
</p>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
  <p>
    Some placeholder content for the collapse component.
  </p>
</div>
```

Any ideas as to what I am missing?

Comment: Use your browser dev tools to check what styling actually applies to the element, and where it originates from.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing

```
.collapse
```

With

```
.collapse:not(.show)
```

Resolved the display issue

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mediaQueryList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList) obejct which uses `window.matchMedia` to set and remove `data-bs-toggle` and reinit collapsible on element to hide on mobile initially.

**Note:** Here on run snippet, it will be collapsed due to considering this iframe as window and evaluating media query accordingly. Try to see result in fullscreen.

```js
const mql = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 767px)");

        const element = document.querySelector('#mobileOnlyCollapse'),
                trigger = document.querySelector('.mobile-only-collapse-trigger');

        let collapseInstance;
        function screenTest(e) {
            if (e.matches) {
                /* the viewport is 767 pixels wide or less */
                trigger.setAttribute('data-bs-toggle','collapse');
                collapseInstance =  new bootstrap.Collapse(element, {})
            } else {
                /* the viewport is more than 767 pixels wide */
                trigger.removeAttribute('data-bs-toggle');
                element.classList.add('show');
            }
        }
        
        // use addEventListener change for mediaQueryList object
        mql.addEventListener("change", screenTest);
        
        //default call with mql object to run on window load
        screenTest(mql);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div>
                        <a role="button" class="btn btn-primary mobile-only-collapse-trigger" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#mobileOnlyCollapse" 
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="mobileOnlyCollapse">
                            Trigger button for mobile collapse
                            
                        </a>
                        <div class="card collapse"  id="mobileOnlyCollapse">
                          <div class="card-body" >
                                <span>This content should be collapsed in mobile only but shown all the time in desktop</span>
                                
                            </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
```